# Norm of the operator $Tv(y)=\int_{-1}^{1}h(x,y)v(x)dx$ is equal to $\sup_{\|v\|=1, v \geq 0} \|Tv\|$ if $h(x,y) \geq 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $h \in L^2([-1,1]\times[-1,1])$ such that $h(x,y) \geq 0$ for all $x,y \in [-1,1]$ and let $T:L^2([-1,1]) \to L^2([-1,1]) $ the operator defined by
$$ Tv(y)=\int_{-1}^{1}h(x,y)v(x)dx.$$
I need to show that $$\|T\|=\sup_{\|v\|=1, v \geq 0} \|Tv\|.$$
Can you give me a hint, please?

Comment: $\left|\int_{-1}^1g(x)\,dx\right|\,\le\,\int_{-1}^1|g(x)|\,dx$.

Comment: Thank you, that inequality is the key to showing the desired equality for $\|T\|$

Comment: By definition $\lVert T\rVert= \sup_{\lVert v\rVert =1} \lVert Tv\rVert$, so it comes down to showing you can restrict the supremum to $v\geq 0$, which should be clear ($\lvert v\rvert$ is in $L^2$ if $v$ is)

Comment: You are right. With help from the above comments I showed the equality for $\|T\|$

Comment: @KwekuA Yes, but it's important that $h\ge 0$. Otherwise this is wrong.